# What is the purpose of AnyVal?

Tags: scala

I can't think of any situation where the type `AnyVal` would be useful, especially with the addition of the `Numeric` type for abstracting over `Int`, `Long`, etc. Are there any actual use cases for `AnyVal`, or is it just an artifact that makes the type hierarchy a bit prettier?

---

Just to clarify, I know what `AnyVal` *is*, I just can't think of any time that I would actually need it in Scala. When would I ever need a type that encompassed `Int`, `Character` and `Double`? It seems like it's just there to make the type hierarchy prettier (i.e. it looks nicer to have `AnyVal` and `AnyRef` as siblings rather than having `Int`, `Character`, etc. inherit directly from `Any`).

Comment: AnyVal is abstraction over primitive types, for example, char is not numeric by meaning, and yet primitive (and represented by AnyVal)

Comment: Paul Phillips once [said](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-language/Y-TpTDOrLSE) that it is time to remove it from the language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's go to the videotape, er, the spec 12.2:

> Value classes are classes whose instances are not represented as
>   objects by the underlying host system. All value classes inherit from
>   class AnyVal.

So, maybe the question is, if everything is an object, why do I care if something is not represented i.e. implemented as an object?  That's the implementation in implementation detail.

But let's not pretend, of course you care. Do you never specialize?

The spec goes on:

> Scala implementations need to provide the value classes Unit, Boolean,
>   Double, Float, Long, Int, Char, Short, and Byte (but are free to
>   provide others as well).

Therefore a test for AnyVal is meaningful, over and above an enumeration of the required value classes.

That said, you must accept @drexin's answer because if you're not using value classes for extension methods, then you're not really living.  (In the sense of, living it up.)

Motivation from the SIP:

> ...classes in Scala that can get completely inlined, so operations on
>   these classes have zero overhead compared to external methods. Some
>   use cases for inlined classes are:
>
> 1. Inlined implicit wrappers. Methods on those wrappers would be
>      translated to extension methods.
> 2. New numeric classes, such as unsigned ints. There would no longer
>      need to be a boxing overhead for such classes. So this is similar to
>      value classes in .NET.
> 3. Classes representing units of measure. Again, no boxing overhead
>      would be incurred for these classes.

You can mark the extension method itself as @inline and everything is inlined: no object wrapper and your little method is inlined.

I use this feature every day.  Yesterday I hit a bug in it.  The bug is already fixed.  What that says is that it's such a cool feature, the Scala folks will take time out from Coursera to quash a little bug in it.

That reminds me, I forgot to ask, this isn't a Coursera quiz question, is it?

Comment: So I guess this means that `AnyVal` is no longer a `sealed trait` in 2.10? Again that's really interesting (+1), but I have a really hard time believing that `AnyVal` doesn't have any practical use in any of _stable_ releases. `AnyVal` looks like it's been around since 2002. There had to be a good use for it between then and when they added the new stuff in Scala 2.10!

Comment: By "specialize" I assume you mean use the `@specialize` annotation, right? I fail to see how that wouldn't work if the primitive types inherited directly from `Any` rather than `AnyVal`. In fact, it would probably make _more_ sense. In that case, `@specialize` would tell the compiler to add a version for _every_ direct subtype of `Any`, i.e. each of the primitives and then one for `AnyRef`.

Comment: I guess that's closer to what I'm asking. However, uses inside the compiler are kind of atypical. Is there an example of somewhere someone might use `AnyVal` outside of Scala compiler code?

Comment: I guess these examples make sense. I'd consider library code way more typical than compiler code, and I can see how you might want to do some special treatment of primitives in library code.

Answer (score 11):

As om-nom-nom already said, `AnyVal` is the common super type of all primitives in scala. In scala 2.10 however, there will be a new feature called `value classes`. Value classes are classes, that can be inlined, with this you can for example reduce the overhead of the extend my library pattern, because there will be no instances of the wrapper classes, that include these methods, instead they will be called statically. You can read everything about value classes in the [SIP-15](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10TQKgMiJTbVtkdRG53wsLYwWM2MkhtmdV25-NZvLLMA/edit?hl=en_US).

Comment: Just to be comprehensive, `AnyVal` is a "sibling" in the hierarchy to `AnyRef` which would be the common super type of all non-primitives in Scala. `Any` is the parent of `AnyVal` and `AnyRef`, and therefore all types in Scala inherit from `Any`, allowing you to do something like: `val anyList: List[Any] = List(1, "Hello", new { def foo = 3 })`

Comment: The bit about _value classes_ is really interesting, thanks for the info! However, I still don't feel like my original question has been answered. (I asked for a use case for `AnyVal`.)

Comment: Value classes are subtypes of `AnyVal`.

Comment: @drexin - What I'm saying is that I see no reason why that subtype relationship makes sense. When would I ever need a supertype that includes all the primitive types but not the reference types? It seems like a more correct (but maybe less pretty) type hierarchy would just have all the primitives inherit directly from `Any`.

Comment: So what I am reading here is that there is one and only one set of use cases for `AnyVal`, and that set of use cases is enabled by the (new as of 2.10) "value classes" feature. So before Scala 2.10, there was really no use case for `AnyVal`. If that's correct, the response should be edited to reflect this clearly.