# When will scala ever return Any?

Tags: scala, inheritance, hierarchy, subtype

I was following the scala course from coursera taught Martin Odersky. He was giving some brilliant examples about return types and one thing puzzled me:

```
if(true) 1 else false // return AnyVal as this is the closest subtype of both primitive types
```

I assume that the following:

```
if(true) Tweet.comment("hello") else String("Hello") // I assume that this code will return AnyRef
```

However when will scala ever return Any? Will it ever return Any?

Comment: `if (cond) 1 else "hello"`. There are two subtypes of `Any` - `AnyVal` and `AnyRef`, so if the two branches return a subtype of each of these, the type of the entire expression will be `Any`.

Comment: @Lee this should be an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Scala, but based on your examples,

```
if(true) 1 else "hello"
```

should probably do the trick.

Comment: IMHO, answers that don't compile shouldn't get the green check.

Answer (score 8):

@dfeuer's answer is correct, I just wanted to add some more information.

`AnyVal` is the base type for primitive types, i.e. `Int`, `Boolean`, `Byte`, etc. In Java, these are the 'keyword' types `int`, `boolean`, `byte`.

`AnyRef` is the base type for reference types, i.e. `java.lang.Object` and just about any `class`.

`Any` is the common type between `AnyVal` and `AnyRef`. In your example, you return `1 else false`, so the compiler looks for the common type between `Int` and `Boolean`, finding `AnyVal`.

If you return `if(true) 1 else "hello"`, it finds the common type between `Int` (an `AnyVal`) and `String` (an `AnyRef`), so it finds `Any`.

Comment: `AnyRef includes just about any class` that isn't `AnyVal`.  Given `class X(val x: Int) extends AnyVal` then `if (true) new X(42) else 42` has type `AnyVal`.

Comment: What function does the `AnyVal` class serve? I imagine there are a lot of things that can be done with `AnyRef` (generic containers, etc.), but raw/unboxed values are highly non-uniform. Does `AnyVal` exist just so you can declare a class to be a value class and have the compiler verify for you that it really is one?

Comment: I can't answer that with any real authority, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655028/what-is-the-purpose-of-anyval) seems related

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
scala> if (true) "hi"
res0: Any = hi
```

That is because [the spec says](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#conditional-expressions) that the else clause is supplied with the Unit value, which is an `AnyVal`:

```
scala> if (true) "hi" else ()
res1: Any = hi
```

That came up on SO a while ago, but I'm not motivated to hunt it down.  The lesson, though, is that one might naively expect the lone `if` to be type Unit.

I just had a compiler error for a recursive function of the form:

```
def f = if (cond) f
```

You have to specify the result type of `f`.